# Improve web scraping speed using parallel processing in R

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing, rselenium

I have a R script which queries a HS Code in a website and fetches the required data and I export this data into an excel book.
But the problem is, for each HS Code, the navigation in the website is longer and it takes almost 1 minute to get the required data. I have 20000 Codes, so this adds up to a long time.
Currently, I'm making 6 RStudio sessions and have splitted the HS codes into 6 files and running the script simultaneously but this requires merging the final files once all sessions are completed and can cause unexpected data mismatch.

I have taken a look at `foreach` package but I could not figure out how to start. Any help is appreciated.
I would like to improve the timeline without having to create multiple sessions.

Current approach of the script is loosely as this:

```
# start the browser
# create a final dataframe
# read the HS Codes
for(i in 1:length(HSCodes)) {
  # open the required page
  # extract the required page
  # merge to the final dataframe
}
```

Comment: I doubt you can speed up web scraping by parallelizing the code, internet speed does not depend on code execution times.

Comment: Figure out how to do what you want by running it sequential with `lapply()`.  When you know that works, then replace with `future_lapply()` of the **future.apply** package to run it in parallel.

Comment: @RuiBarradas, what i mean is, at a time is it possible to open ~4 browsers so that 4that many codes are queried opposed to one at a time using for loop.

Comment: @HenrikB, I will take a look at your package. thanks!